# Sails Not Caching Compressed Files

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, sails.js

Any idea why Chrome is not caching gzip files from Sails or Express?

Files not cached: `js`, `css`

Files cached: `png`, `woff`

Response header for javascript

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 17:37:01 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 17:10:18 GMT
ETag: W/"fKReHkHilgulZYl81EvdUg=="
Content-Type: application/javascript
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Response Header for image

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 17:37:02 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 17:10:18 GMT
ETag: W/"d+496iEH7ze9Df3G7Jytiw=="
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 4121
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: I am having the same problem...did you find a solution?

Comment: nope... no solution so far, but it seems more of a chrome problem than sails

Comment: Are you on SSL? I did some investigation and found it was linked to chrome's handling cache on SSL connections. Can you test without SSL and let me know please?